# Is it possible to remove the label on lightning:namespace components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I would like to use the lightning:input component in a data table.
Therefore my question is:
Is it possible to remove the label attribute on the lightning component?

```
<lightning:input type="number" label=" " name="aNumberInputField" />
```

is quite not the solution for this (shifted... doesn't look good), and removing the attribute throws an error.
Any advise?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes you can set the `variant` attribute to `"label-hidden"`, so your code should look like:

```
<lightning:input type="number" label="number" variant = "label-hidden" name="aNumberInputField"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice new variant. Thank you! No additional css anymore :)

Answer (score 16):

If you still want to use the lightning base components without the labels you can put the display to none and the visibility to hidden like this

```
.THIS .slds-form-element__label {
      display : none;
      visibility : hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll use it like this:
.THIS .nolabel .slds-form-element__label{
 display: none;
 visibility: hidden
}

Answer (score 4):

The `label` property, for now, is mandatory on that control. It may not be a perfect fit, but the set of `<ui:inputXXX>` controls provide very similar functionality without the requirement for a label. You may find that you have to recreate some functionality (depending on your needs), but you'll be very nearly there from the get go.